# How to open the default file explorer in shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, file-manager

Different Linux distro have different file explorer. Is there any universal way(type the same command) to open the file explorer to a certain directory in shell(command line)?

If it is possible, it is better to be suitable for any Unix-like OS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like `xdg-open /path/to/directory`, which should open up in the default file explorer. Of course, this only works on systems where `xdg`-like stuff is installed (so I would imagine mostly Linux systems).